# Python-2.7 Scapy -- send multiple arp requests simultaniously

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

How can I create a script which would take the couple of variables and use them as ip_src and the other ip_dest? Passing them in the script, it would send the arp request in a loop

```
dict1 = {"192.168.1.4":"192.168.1.6","192.168.1.4":"192.168.1.3","192.168.1.4":"192.168.1.1"}
#the first item in the dict is the ip_scr and the second is the ip_dest
for *couple*?? in dict1:
    send([ARP(op=ARP.who_has, psrc=ip_src, pdst=ip_dest)], loop = 1)
```

Second problem is that, since the script do not stop, it will not do the second couple and third and etc...

Comment: Just for clarification, every entry in the dictionary is the source/dest pairs right? So your first run through the for loop would ideally be `send([ARP(op=ARP.who_has, psrc="192.168.1.4", pdst="192.168.1.6")], loop = 1)` is that correct?

Comment: @dbishop thats right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in [*Scapy*'s official API documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf), the first argument of the `send()` function may be a list of packets:

> `pkts` can be a packet, an implicit packet or a list of them.

Therefore, the following should send all of the required packets in an endless loop:

```
send([ARP(op=ARP.who_has, psrc=ip_src, pdst=ip_dst) for ip_src, ip_dst in dict1.viewitems()], loop=1)
```

Comment: I tried this in python3 : from scapy.all import *
dict1 = {"192.168.5.51":"192.168.5.46","192.168.5.51":"192.168.5.11"}

send([ARP(op=ARP.who_has, psrc=ip_src, pdst=ip_dst) for ip_src, ip_dst in dict1.items()], loop = 1, inter=3)     But it just sent packets to 192.168.5.11! Why so?

Comment: That seems unreasonable since the values of the `ip_dst` field differ. Can you test it again?

Comment: Alright, tried it for the last hour and here what I found: if the ip_src in the dict is always the same, it only sends one of the ip_dst (the last one in the dict). Second of all, it doesn't work when doing this : send([ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=router_ip, hwdst=victim_mac, pdst=victim_ip),
      ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=victim_ip, hwdst=router_mac, pdst=router_ip)for victim_ip, victim_mac in dict1.viewitems()],
     inter=3, loop=1) --- it brings this error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Oh, the problem is in your definition of `dict1`. You're trying to map two different values (`"192.168.5.46"` and `"192.168.5.11"`) to the same key (`"192.168.5.51"`). The second mapping attempt overrides the first one, thereby creating `dict1` as `{'192.168.5.51': '192.168.5.11'}`. Thus, the `for` loop generates a single _ARP_ packet with `192.168.5.11` as the destination.

Comment: Right! One last thing, when I do 2 commands in 1 send packet, the for loop doesn't work  : send([ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=router_ip, hwsrc=router_mac, hwdst=victim_mac, pdst=victim_ip),ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=victim_ip, hwsrc=victim_mac, hwdst=router_mac, pdst=router_ip) for victim_ip,victim_mac in full.viewitems()],
     inter=3, loop=1)

Comment: The list comprehension syntax doesn't support extending the generated list by more than a single item in each iteration. Therefore, try using this: `send([ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=router_ip, hwsrc=router_mac, hwdst=victim_mac, pdst=victim_ip) for victim_ip, victim_mac in full.viewitems()] + [ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=victim_ip, hwsrc=victim_mac, hwdst=router_mac, pdst=router_ip) for victim_ip, victim_mac in full.viewitems()], inter=3, loop=1)`.